# is there is any analytical tools for Nokia S40?

Tags: analytics, nokia, nokia-s40

I have a question , is there is any analytical tools for Nokia S40 devices such as Flurry analytics For android and iphone ??

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Series_40/ "Series 40 offers you two great development technologies: Java and web apps".

Assuming you are using Java ME, you can try http://j2megroup.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/new-version-of-google-analytics-me-v21.html and all application statistics will be stored on a Google Analytics account.